# Form news duplicate

Tags: php, mysql

i'm not an expert developer, but i created an editor that post my news. 
But every time that i update the page (with f5 or something else) i found a new article in my database. So my database is full with a single article. 
There's an example: https://image.prntscr.com/image/3z0d-9I5S9OUdGBCaytz2Q.png
This is my code, where am i wrong?

```
 <?php

require_once('../db_conf.php');

$id = $key;

    $titolo = addslashes($_POST['titolo']);
    $immagine = addslashes($_POST['immagine']);
    $anteprima = addslashes($_POST['anteprima']);
    $testo = addslashes($_POST['testo']);
    $autore = addslashes($_POST['autore']);


mysql_query("INSERT INTO news (titolo,immagine,anteprima,testo,data,autore) VALUES ('".$titolo."','".$immagine."','".$anteprima."','".$testo."','".$date_full."','".$autore."')") or die(mysql_error());



?>


        <main class="col-sm-9 ml-sm-auto col-md-10 pt-3" role="main">
        <center>  <h1>Inserisci News</h1></center>


       <center> 
          <FORM METHOD="post" ACTION="<? echo $PHP_SELF; ?>">
<div class="form-group sp-wdg5"><label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Titolo:</label>
<div class="col-sm-10"><input type="text" name="titolo" value class="form-control"></div>
</div>
<div class="form-group sp-wdg5"><label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Immagine:</label>
<div class="col-sm-10"><input type="text" name="immagine" value class="form-control"></div>
</div>
<div class="form-group sp-wdg5"><label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Testo di Anteprima:</label>
<div class="col-sm-10"><input type="text" name="anteprima" value class="form-control"></div>
</div>
          <script type="text/javascript" src="/tinymce/js/tinymce/tinymce.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
tinymce.init({
        selector: "textarea",
        language : "it",
        plugins: [
                "advlist autolink autosave link lists charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak image imagetools",
                "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen insertdatetime media",
                "table contextmenu directionality emoticons textcolor paste fullpage textcolor colorpicker textpattern"
        ],

        toolbar1: "bold italic underline strikethrough cut copy paste alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | searchreplace | bullist numlist | outdent indent blockquote | styleselect formatselect fontselect fontsizeselect",
        toolbar2: "undo redo | link unlink anchor image media code |  preview | forecolor backcolor | table | hr removeformat",
        toolbar3: "charmap | print fullscreen | ltr rtl | spellchecker | visualchars visualblocks nonbreaking template pagebreak restoredraft",

        menubar: false,
        toolbar_items_size: 'small',

        style_formats: [
                {title: 'Bold text', inline: 'b'},
                {title: 'Red text', inline: 'span', styles: {color: '#ff0000'}},
                {title: 'Red header', block: 'h1', styles: {color: '#ff0000'}},
                {title: 'Example 1', inline: 'span', classes: 'example1'},
                {title: 'Example 2', inline: 'span', classes: 'example2'},
                {title: 'Table styles'},
                {title: 'Table row 1', selector: 'tr', classes: 'tablerow1'}
        ],

        templates: [
                {title: 'Test template 1', content: 'Test 1'},
                {title: 'Test template 2', content: 'Test 2'}
        ],
  imagetools_toolbar: "rotateleft rotateright | flipv fliph | editimage imageoptions",
  imagetools_cors_hosts: ['/']
});</script>
<div class="row container-modifica">
<div class="col-lg-12">
<div class="ibox float-e-margins">

<div class="ibox-content">
<div class="col-container-modifica">

<div class="hr-line-dashed"></div>
<div class="form-group">
<div class="col-sm-10">
<div class="editor-special-news">
<textarea name='testo' cols='70' rows='25' width="20" wrap='soft' id='testo' class='multitext'></textarea>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group sp-wdg5"><label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Autore:</label>
<div class="col-sm-10"><input type="text" name="autore" value class="form-control"></div>
</div>
<button type="submit" accesskey="s" class="btn btn-w-m btn-info"> Aggiungi </button></FORM>
</center>
```

Comment: Every time you update (F5) you're causing the form to be resubmitted.

Comment: wrap the beginning section (the insert) in a `if(isset($_POST['titolo'])) { your code }`

Comment: and switch on [error_reporting](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) while developing!

Comment: Please ditch the deprecated mysql_* functions and addslashes, for something like mysqli_* with prepared statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need a button submit.If the button was clicked Your code will run

```
<?php

    require_once('../db_conf.php');
    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    $id = $key;

        $titolo = addslashes($_POST['titolo']);
        $immagine = addslashes($_POST['immagine']);
        $anteprima = addslashes($_POST['anteprima']);
        $testo = addslashes($_POST['testo']);
        $autore = addslashes($_POST['autore']);


    mysql_query("INSERT INTO news (titolo,immagine,anteprima,testo,data,autore) VALUES ('".$titolo."','".$immagine."','".$anteprima."','".$testo."','".$date_full."','".$autore."')") or die(mysql_error());


    }
    ?>


            <main class="col-sm-9 ml-sm-auto col-md-10 pt-3" role="main">
            <center>  <h1>Inserisci News</h1></center>


           <center> 
              <FORM METHOD="post" ACTION="<? echo $PHP_SELF; ?>">
    <div class="form-group sp-wdg5"><label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Titolo:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10"><input type="text" name="titolo" value class="form-control"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group sp-wdg5"><label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Immagine:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10"><input type="text" name="immagine" value class="form-control"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group sp-wdg5"><label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Testo di Anteprima:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10"><input type="text" name="anteprima" value class="form-control"></div>
<div class="col-sm-10"><input class="form-control btn btn-primary"  type="submit" value="Send it!"></div>
    </div>
```